# Oracle SQL Developer - SUBSTR and LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, sql-like

I have a column NAME_SURNAME (made of names and surnames) from a table people:

```
John Smith
Tim Burton
Harry Potter
```

I need to write a query to obtain only the names:

```
John
Tim
Harry
```

I am trying in this way nad it doesn't work:

```
select NAME_SURNAME, substr(NAME_SURNAME, 1, LIKE '% %')
from PEOPLE
```

I don't figure out how to use LIKE in this exercise.

Thank you really much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INSTR` with `SUBSTR` to take a substring up to the first space:

```sql
SELECT NAME_SURNAME, SUBSTR(NAME_SURNAME, 1, INSTR(NAME_SURNAME, ' ') - 1)
FROM PEOPLE;
```

### Demo

For a regex approach, we can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT NAME_SURNAME, REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME_SURNAME, '^\S+') AS FIRST_NAME
FROM PEOPLE;
```